# I would like to change a ggplot entirely to another one through a SelectInput

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W9PAI.png) Currently I have a selectInput with two options which I want to link to their own ggplots entirely. What I currently have is only seeming to show the second ggplot when its Input in the drop down is selected, but the first plot for "Ordered_Product_Sales" is not showing. Wondering where I am going wrong whether it is in the IF statements or just my structure entirely. I am very new (couple of days) to R and R shiny so be kind.

```
library(shiny)
library(plotly)

 ui <- fluidPage(

    # Application title
    titlePanel("Metric Tracker"),


    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            selectInput("value", "Select Value" , choices = c("Ordered_Product_Sales", "Units_Ordered"), selected = NULL ,  multiple = FALSE, selectize = TRUE)

        ),

        # Show plot
        mainPanel(
           plotlyOutput("valuePlot"),
           plotlyOutput("value2Plot")
        )
    )
)

# Define server
server <- function(input, output) {

output$valuePlot <- renderPlotly({
    if (input$value == "Ordered_Product_Sales")
        metric2 %>%
            ggplot(aes(x=Date, y = Ordered_Product_Sales, title = "Sales")) + geom_point() + geom_line( ) + geom_smooth(method = 'lm') + facet_wrap( ~ Brand)

    output$value2Plot <- renderPlotly({   
     if (input$value == "Units_Ordered")
        metric2 %>% 
            ggplot(aes(x=Date, y = Units_Ordered)) + geom_point() + geom_line() + geom_smooth(method = 'lm') + facet_wrap( ~ Brand)


    })

    })
}

# Run the application 

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

My Data is called metric2 where the ggplots are plotting the date against either the sales column or units column.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try the below simplified version of your code. You might need to provide some dummy data if this still doesn't work.

```
library(shiny)
library(plotly)

ui <- fluidPage(

    # Application title
    titlePanel("Metric Tracker"),


    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            selectInput("value", "Select Value" , choices = c("Ordered_Product_Sales", "Units_Ordered"), selected = NULL ,  multiple = FALSE, selectize = TRUE)

        ),

        # Show plot
        mainPanel(
            plotlyOutput("valuePlot")
        )
    )
)

# Define server
server <- function(input, output) {

    output$valuePlot <- renderPlotly({
        if (input$value == "Ordered_Product_Sales") {
            metric2 %>%
                ggplot(aes(x=Date, y = Ordered_Product_Sales)) + geom_point() + geom_line( ) + geom_smooth(method = 'lm') + facet_wrap( ~ Brand) + ggtitle("Sales")
        }
        if (input$value == "Units_Ordered") {
            metric2 %>% 
                ggplot(aes(x=Date, y = Units_Ordered)) + geom_point() + geom_line() + geom_smooth(method = 'lm') + facet_wrap( ~ Brand)
        }
    })
}

# Run the application 

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

**Update**

Based on the image of the data, I created a small sample set:

```
metric2 = data.frame(Date = c(as.POSIXct('2019-07-06'), as.POSIXct('2019-07-07'), as.POSIXct('2019-07-08'), as.POSIXct('2019-07-06'), as.POSIXct('2019-07-06')), Brand = c('A', 'B', 'A', 'C', 'B'), Units_Ordered = c(710, 253, 185, 107, 727), Ordered_Product_Sales = c(6551, 7226, 9007, 6003, 5964), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

And then updated the app as follows:

```
library(shiny)
library(plotly)

ui <- fluidPage(

    # Application title
    titlePanel("Metric Tracker"),


    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            selectInput("value", "Select Value" , choices = c("Ordered_Product_Sales", "Units_Ordered"), selected = NULL ,  multiple = FALSE, selectize = TRUE)

        ),

        # Show plot
        mainPanel(
            plotlyOutput("valuePlot")
        )
    )
)

# Define server
server <- function(input, output) {

    output$valuePlot <- renderPlotly({
        if (input$value == "Ordered_Product_Sales") {
            metric2_plot <- metric2 %>%
                ggplot(aes(x=Date, y = Ordered_Product_Sales)) + geom_point() + geom_line( ) + geom_smooth(method = 'lm') + facet_wrap( ~ Brand) + ggtitle("Sales")
        }
        if (input$value == "Units_Ordered") {
            metric2_plot <- metric2 %>% 
                ggplot(aes(x=Date, y = Units_Ordered)) + geom_point() + geom_line() + geom_smooth(method = 'lm') + facet_wrap( ~ Brand)
        }
        metric2_plot
    })
}

# Run the application 

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

The key is that `renderPlotly()` returns the last object created/value returned within it (as do all `renders` and `reactives`). The second if statement comes after the `ggplot` creation and, as it's `FALSE`, it returns `NULL` which can't be plotted. (There is an implicit `...else{NULL}` after an if statement.) So your options are either the above where I created `metric2_plot` and then explicitly return it at the end of the `renderPlotly()`or to use an `if...else` so that the `ggplot` creation occurs after the only if statement is evaluated as below:

```
output$valuePlot <- renderPlotly({
    if (input$value == "Ordered_Product_Sales") {
        metric2 %>%
            ggplot(aes(x=Date, y = Ordered_Product_Sales)) + geom_point() + geom_line( ) + geom_smooth(method = 'lm') + facet_wrap( ~ Brand) + ggtitle("Sales")
    }
    else {
        metric2 %>% 
            ggplot(aes(x=Date, y = Units_Ordered)) + geom_point() + geom_line() + geom_smooth(method = 'lm') + facet_wrap( ~ Brand)
    }

})
```

**Finally**, please replace `, title = "Sales"` in `aes` with `+ ggtitle("Sales")`.

Comment: Hi Thank you for your response. However, the first plot still is not showing unfortunately. I am trying to attach a screen grab of metric 2 but i'm struggling. Bare with

Comment: Glad to hear! :)